# How to put variable inside array?

Tags: php, arrays, compression

I'm trying to put a variable inside array $filename.
The code below is working:

```
$files = array('http://xyz.xyz/subtitle/contributor/subtitle/file/The.Bourne.Legacy.2012.All.BluRayRip.1080p.720p.and.Ganool.sebuah-dongeng.blogspot.com.srt');
```

BUT, I want to put the variable $data['zipname'] inside the array $files
so that the variable will change according to the data from DB.

So far, the compression is working, but I can't find out how to make the array get the right link.

```
$files = array('http://xyz.xyz/contributor/sub/file/".$data['zipname']."');

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$tmp_file = tempnam('temp','');

$zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);

foreach($files as $file){
    $download_file = file_get_contents($file);
    $zip->addFromString(basename($file),$download_file);
}

$zip->close();

header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=download.zip');
header('Content-type: application/zip');
readfile($tmp_file);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If double quote `"` is unnecessary:

```
$files = array('http://xyz.xyz/contributor/sub/file/' . $data['zipname'] );
```

If its required:

```
$files = array('http://xyz.xyz/contributor/sub/file/"' . $data['zipname'] . '"' );
```

Comment: thank you i found out the problem,im to high when i wrote the code.

Answer (score 0):

> how to put variable inside an array

Use **double-quotes** and **curly braces** to **expand** the variable `$data['zipname']` inside the `array`, i.e.:

```
$files = array("http://xyz.xyz/contributor/sub/file/{$data['zipname']}");
```